# Updating matplotlib figures within a for loop in python

Tags: loops, matplotlib, magpylib

I am trying to move a magnetic object and update its magnetic field which is then plotted in a for loop. I want to update the matplotlib figures such that the last figure is deleted before the latest one is shown (with delay as can be seen). I want this to happen in one window (I might be using the wrong technical term) only. Currently it creates a new figure every time it updates the magnetic field. I tried using plt.cla(), plt.close(), and plt.clf() without success. The code is given below. Any help will be much appreciated

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from magpylib.source.magnet import Box,Cylinder
from magpylib import Collection, displaySystem

# create magnets
s1 = Box(mag=(0,0,600), dim=(3,3,3), pos=(-4,0,20))

# calculate the grid
xs = np.linspace(-15,10,33)
zs = np.linspace(-5,25,44)
POS = np.array([(x,0,z) for z in zs for x in xs])
X,Z = np.meshgrid(xs,zs)

for i in range(20):
    Bs = s1.getB(POS).reshape(44,33,3)     #B-field
    s1.move((0,0,-1))

    # create figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,9))

    # display field in xz-plane using matplotlib
    U,V = Bs[:,:,0], Bs[:,:,2]
    plt.streamplot(X, Z, U, V, color=np.log(U**2+V**2))

    plt.show()
    
    sleep(0.2)```
````

Comment: Maybe [animation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/animation_api.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You want to make use of matplotlib's interactive mode by invoking `plt.ion()` and clear the axes after every frame in the loop using `plt.cla()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from magpylib.source.magnet import Box,Cylinder
from magpylib import Collection, displaySystem
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# create magnets
s1 = Box(mag=(0,0,600), dim=(3,3,3), pos=(-4,0,20))

# calculate the grid
xs = np.linspace(-15,10,33)
zs = np.linspace(-5,25,44)
POS = np.array([(x,0,z) for z in zs for x in xs])
X,Z = np.meshgrid(xs,zs)
plt.ion()
plt.show()

img=0
for i in range(20):
    Bs = s1.getB(POS).reshape(44,33,3)     #B-field
    s1.move((0,0,-1))
    U,V = Bs[:,:,0], Bs[:,:,2]
    ax.streamplot(X, Z, U, V, color=np.log(U**2+V**2))    
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    plt.savefig('{}'.format(img))
    plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.clf()
    img=img+1
```

Comment: Hi @Sameeresque, thank you so much. It renders much slower on macOS and Windows. How do I speed it up and match the frame rate that you have going on over here. I am using the exact code you published. Apparently, changing pause value doesnt do much

Comment: The gif shown here is generated by stitching together 20 saved png images. You can control the frame rate by adjusting the delay parameter. `convert -delay 5 -loop 0 {0..20}.png output.gif`. You will need to have ImageMagick installed to make use of this command.